# Searching names in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have *users* table: id, first_name, last_name, ...

With data:

- 1, John, Doe
- 2, Harry, Potter
- 3, Alex, Brown
- 4, James, Smith

I need to make autocomplete feature, when user press "H", in result must be only three rows, row with id 2 must be first because it contains "h" and it starts with "h", second must be row with id 1, because it contains "h" and it is before others that contain "h", third should must be row with id 4, because it contains "h".

How must be this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `like` and `position`:

```
select t.name
from t
where lower(t.name) like '%h%'
order by position('h' in t.name);
```

EDIT:

I notice your query has two name fields.  Just concatenate them together:

```
select t.first_name, t.last_name
from t
where lower(t.first_name || ' ' || t.last_name) like '%h%'
order by position('h' in t.first_name || ' ' || t.last_name);
```

Note:  The space is unnecessary in the concatenation.  It just seems to make sense to me.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to concatenate only once?

Comment: You could use a CTE, subquery, or lateral join -- but that really seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strpos()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
with my_table(id, name, surname) as (
values
    (1, 'John', 'Doe'),
    (2, 'Harry', 'Potter'),
    (3, 'Alex', 'Brown'),
    (4, 'James', 'Smith')
)

select id, name, surname
from (
    select *, strpos(lower(name), 'h') p1, strpos(lower(surname), 'h') p2
    from my_table
    ) s
where p1 <> 0 or p2 <> 0
order by case p1 
    when 0 then p2 
    else case p2 
        when 0 then p1 
        else least(p1, p2) 
        end 
    end;

 id | name  | surname 
----+-------+---------
  2 | Harry | Potter
  1 | John  | Doe
  4 | James | Smith
(3 rows)
```